# How to fetch JSON data in Android when URL is separated with hyphen?

Tags: android, json, gson

I want to fetch JSON data. I have done it lots of time but my problem is my `url` is separated in hyphen. I see here so many people tell that we have to encode URLs but I want to ask you how to encode it and any other solution instead of encoding URL.

Following is my code.

When user enter electricity details on my app this URL is form and if details are valid it will fetch electricity bill for me.

http://myurl.com/Index/FetchElectricityBills?billdetail=58-49012520599-4678-01

In this URL all parameters are separated with hyphen. Here `58` is `opreterID`,  `49012520599` is `consumerNumber`, `4678` is `bilingUnit` and `01` is `processingCycle`:

```java
String abc = 58+"-"+edit_consumer_number.getText()+"-"+spinner_1.getText()+"-"+spinner_2.getText();
```

For testing purpose I provide `orpretor` ID by default. The `getBillDetails` method:

```java
private void GetBillDetails(String abc) {

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    MobilePlansClient mobilePlansClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(MobilePlansClient.class);
    Call<String> cart  = mobilePlansClient.getElectricity(abc);
    /*Call<List<BillPaymentOpreatorModel>> getElectricityBills = mobilePlansClient.getElectricityBills();*/
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    cart.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "3"+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //  edt_amount.setText("3"+response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "4"+t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Web service:

```java
@GET("Index/FetchElectricityBills")
Call<String> getElectricity(@Query("billdetail") String abc);
```

Get bill details model:

```java
public class GetBillModel {

    @SerializedName("billdetail")
    @Expose
    private Integer billdetail;

}
```

I have spend my two days but not get solution. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Try this: String abc = "58"  + "-" + edit_consumer_number.getText().toString() + "-" + spinner_1.getText().toString() + "-" + spinner_2.getText().toString();

Comment: Even I have used retrofit2 and my url contains "-" (hyphen) but till now I have not encountered any issues with it please let us know the error which your are getting?

Comment: @ReyanshMishra java.lang.illegalstateexception expected a string but was begin_object at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: @kunal nikam that means that you are able to get the data but you are not parsing is properly show us your retrieved json string and the model class in which you are parsing it.

Comment: Hello @kunal nikam, I'm in a similar situation here, how were you able to solve please

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use Retrofit encode attribute ? for example :

```
@GET("Index/FetchElectricityBills")
Call<String> getElectricity(@Query(value="billdetail", encoded=true) String abc);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I see the exception on your comment , it's a format issue catch by Gson when you retrieved the data , not a encode issue. Can you share the model of the data that you must fetch ?

Answer (score 0):

if GetBillModel is your model class then your interface should return this class 
like this

```
@GET("Index/FetchElectricityBills")
Call<GetBillModel> getElectricity(@Query("billdetail") String abc);
```

and in your GetBillModel class parse the json data properly then only you will be able to get the data for example:
this is your json string

```
{
   "data": {
     "name":"electricity bill"
   }
}
```

then your GetBillModel class should look like this

```
public class GetBillModel{
@SerializedName("data")
    public Data data;

    public static class Data {
        @SerializedName("name")
        public String name;
    }
}
```

here the "data" is an object and "name" is string.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**According:**

[Wrong URl symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104092/retrofit-calling-wrong-url-if-url-string-contains-symbol-causes-404-error)

In the RFC the following characters:

Unreserved Characters

Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved purpose are called unreserved. These include uppercase and lowercase letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.

unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
Berners-Lee, et al. Standards Track [Page 13]

RFC 3986 URI Generic Syntax January 2005

URIs that differ in the replacement of an unreserved character with its corresponding percent-encoded US-ASCII octet are equivalent: they identify the same resource. However, URI comparison implementations do not always perform normalization prior to comparison (see Section 6). For consistency, percent-encoded octets in the ranges of ALPHA (%41-%5A and %61-%7A), DIGIT (%30-%39), hyphen (%2D), period (%2E), underscore (%5F), or tilde (%7E) should not be created by URI producers and, when found in a URI, should be decoded to their corresponding unreserved characters by URI normalizers.