# Retrofit calling wrong url if url string contains "~" symbol causes 404 Error

Tags: android, retrofit

I have created retrofit client and api interface but retrofit skipping some part in url and calling wrong url

here is full url 
http://192.168.0.201/~amol/eflbudget/budgetmanagements/test

url which retrofit calling 
http://192.168.0.201/budgetmanagements/test/

this causing 404 error

```
//here is my retrofit client code 

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();

    if (retrofit != null) {
        return retrofit;
    }

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.201/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(client)
            .build();

    return retrofit;
}

// below is api call
@Multipart
@POST("/~amol/eflbudget/budgetmanagements/test/")
Call<ResponseBody> postMail(
        @Part("user_id") RequestBody userId,
        @Part("lead_id") RequestBody leadId,
        @Part("to") RequestBody to,
        @Part("cc_to") RequestBody ccId,
        @Part("template_id") RequestBody tempId,
        @Part("sender") RequestBody senderId,
        @Part("subject") RequestBody subject,
        @Part("message") RequestBody message,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file
);
```

expected api url : http://192.168.0.201/~amol/eflbudget/budgetmanagements/test

actual url:
http://192.168.0.201/budgetmanagements/test/

here /~amol/eflbudget this part in url getting ignored
can anyone suggest somethings here?

Comment: Interface method start without `/` in retrofit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) the following characters:

**Unreserved Characters**

Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase
letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.

```
  unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

Berners-Lee, et al.         Standards Track                    [Page 13]

RFC 3986                   URI Generic Syntax               January 2005

URIs that differ in the replacement of an unreserved character with
its corresponding percent-encoded US-ASCII octet are equivalent: they
identify the same resource.  However, URI comparison implementations
do not always perform normalization prior to comparison (see Section
6).  For consistency, percent-encoded octets in the ranges of ALPHA
(%41-%5A and %61-%7A), DIGIT (%30-%39), hyphen (%2D), period (%2E),
underscore (%5F), or tilde (%7E) should not be created by URI
producers and, when found in a URI, should be decoded to their
corresponding unreserved characters by URI normalizers.

Comment: Thanks sushil, I have modified my api path like                                                             
" @POST("/%7Eamol/eflbudget/budgetmanagements/test/")" but still facing same problem

Comment: use like this @POST("%7Eamol/eflbudget/budgetmanagements/test/"). Retrofit method url doesn't have `/` in start .

Comment: here are logs : D/OkHttp: --> GET  http://192.168.0.201/~amol/eflbudget/budgetmanagements/test/ http/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- 404 Not Found http://192.168.0.201/budgetmanagements/test it's calling same url but still getting 404

Comment: I have replaced "~" this character with "%7E" and it worked for request. but for response i could not able to find way to replace this. it fixed problem but i need to fix it response too. getting response like 192.168.0.201/budgetmanagements/test

Comment: you have to change response url also